# bash: ./configure: Permission denied how can I fix this

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, kivymd, termux

I m trying to use buildozer in termux everything is fine but it was asking to install zlib

So I found this discussion :-

https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/2671

But when I ran command
`./configure --prefix=$PREFIX`

And I got this error
**bash: ./configure: Permission denied**

How can I fix this??

Comment: You typically need root to `make install` packages. Configure simply prepares for the make.

Comment: What are file permissions? "Permission denied" while executing (not while already running) usually means the file is not executable. `chmod +x configure` would fix it